# Is it possible to castle with checkmate?

Tags: rules, checkmate, castling, check

I am new to chess.  Please answer this for me:

> Is it possible to castle with checkmate?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Jethik. I edited the language of your post a bit, but I'm not sure exactly what your question is. Does either of the answers below address what you're looking for, or is it something else?

Comment: checkmate immediately ends the game. nothing else is possible after that.

Comment: You could castle and perform checkmate with that move, though it's not common.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I can think of two questions you might be meaning to ask, given the wording of your question. Maybe neither of these is what you're after, but just in case:

**1. Is it possible to castle out of check or even checkmate?** Here the answer is *no*. If your king is in check, then castling is not a legal move.

**2. Is it possible to castle while checkmating your opponent?** Here the answer is *yes*, it is possible, though it does not happen often. For instance, the game [Ed.Lasker-Thomas (1912)](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1259009), with its famous queen sacrifice and king hunt, could have finished with a castling mate:

```
[fen ""]
1. d4 e6 2. Nf3 f5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. Bg5 Be7 5. Bxf6 Bxf6 6. e4
fxe4 7. Nxe4 b6 8. Ne5 O-O 9. Bd3 Bb7 10. Qh5 Qe7 11. Qxh7+
Kxh7 12. Nxf6+ Kh6 13. Neg4+ Kg5 14. h4+ Kf4 15. g3+ Kf3
16. Be2+ Kg2 17. Rh2+ Kg1 18. Kd2# (18.O-O-O#)1-0
```

Comment: Paul Morphy vs Alonzo Morphy from 1850 in which Paul Morphy checkmates his opponent via castling kingside: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1238144

Answer (score 3):

If you I asking whether it is legal to castle out of checkmate if it is the only option then no the same rules apply as with check although I can't really think of many instances where you would be able to castle to prevent checkmate...

Answer (score 3):

No-if check mate for your king.
Yes- if check mate for opponent's king

Answer (score 2):

This was achieved by Eric Rosen (IM) on his Twitch stream, uploaded to YouTube Dec 2019.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxZc7ZF2uOY

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it clearly is possible. Here is a position where White has just castled, and checkmated.

```
    8/8/8/8/8/8/R7/2KR2k1 w - - 0 1
```